# ¿Qué es un vector de datos en Python

Tags: python

Este tema corresponde a cadena de caracteres crear una cadena con dos variables, de modo que, debajo de cada variable, utilicé `name1 = 'Sé'` y `name2 = 'feliz'`, con `print(name1)` y `print(name2)`.

Comment: Este tipo de pregunta es más para ChatGPT que para StackOverflow. De todas formas te invito a que replantees tu consulta, mostranos que intentaste y que error tuviste, de modo a ayudarte a encontrar una solución, no a hacer los ejercicios del curso.

Comment: En Python no hay *vectores*. Existen varios tipos de [estructuras](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html): listas, tuplas, sets, diccionarios, cadenas, objetos... Cada una tiene su comportamiento y forma parte del manual básico del lenguaje que debes estudiar a conciencia. Concatener esas 2 cadenas en un `print`, se puede hacer de muchas formas: `print(name1 + ' ' + name2)` o `print(name1, name2)` o `print(f'{name1} {name2}')` o `print('{} {}'.format(name1, name2))` y hay más. Tu decides qué quieres.